# Does "and" come from the PIE word for "and"?

Tags: english, etymology, proto-indo-european

From the [etymology of and](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=and&searchmode=none):

> Old English and, ond, originally meaning "thereupon, next," from Proto-Germanic *unda (cf. Old Saxon endi, Old Frisian anda, Middle Dutch ende, Old High German enti, German und, Old Norse enn), from PIE *en; cognate with Latin ante, Greek anti (see ante). Phrase and how as an exclamation of emphatic agreement dates from early 1900s.

Since "and" is one of the most common words, I had expected it to trace back all the way to PIE, like words like mother or father, for example, but instead it seems it meant "thereupon, next" as recently as Old English.

So, I have these questions:

- Is "and" a recent word?
- If so, what word performed its function before that?
- Did PIE have an unrelated word for "and", and if so, why did such a common word fall away from usage?
- Is "and" a cognate to Latin "et"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the quote in your question you can see that `and` derives from Proto-Germanic so I don't think that we can call it "recent".

Also, according to the quote in your question, `and` is related to Latin `ante` and not to Latin [et](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et#Latin).

PIE [*-kʷe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/-k%CA%B7e#Proto-Indo-European) ([IELex](http://ielex.mpi.nl/meaning/and/languagelist/all/)) is generally given as "and" which is related to Latin `-que` and, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_vocabulary#Pronouns.2C_particles), to English (thou)**gh**.

I believe it's unlikely for historical linguistics to be able to answer the "why" question in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the link you mention is at wiktionary.org. Is it a reliable etymology? Anyone could have written it. They give a warning that "This entry includes a list of references, related reading or external links, but its sources remain unclear because it lacks inline citations. Please improve this entry by introducing more precise citations, inserting <ref> tags where appropriate".

Comment: I understand. Are you expecting a publicly available, online source or would you prefer a citation from a published etymological dictionary?

Comment: I added the entry for PIE *-kʷe from IELex which is associated with the Max Planck Institute for Psycholinguistics.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to know what you're doing, so that's enough for me.

Comment: Well, I don't know that your statement is actually true... ;-) And asking for a **real** source is a reasonable request.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to explain myself exactly - I didn't know if you are a professional linguist (I myself am not, I'm just curious about it), and you might have been a good intentioned hobbyist who  somehow landed on wiktionary.org (by Google searching), and pasted the link without even realizing why it might be problematic. I mean there's no way to know who on this site actually knows a lot about the subject.

Comment: @sashoalm There is a way to know, by proxy, who on this site "knows a lot about the subject": it's the reputation score. As you provide answers and comments, other users of the site either vote them up for usefulness or the opposite - and you get rewarded/substracted reputation points for that. Over time the effect is cumulative so if you see an answer from someone who has a very large reputation, you know it comes from someone perceived as knowledgeable by the community.

Comment: @sashoalm: Are you aware that "anyone could've written" the etymology on etymonline as well? There's no "*the* etymology" just as there's no "*the* dictionary". The person behind etymonline is not a professional etymologist, lexicographer, or linguist as far as I can recall. They do an excellent job I have to say. But that doesn't mean we know if they copy them straight out of Wester's, out of the OED, hunt through obscure etymologial dictionaries, keep up with current etymological work by professional, throw in their own theories, etc. Often different sources will have different etyms ...

Comment: Actually [etymonline does tell us their sources these days](http://etymonline.com/index.php), and perhaps always did. What I said was based on some correspondence from some years ago. Still, while it should be more reliable than Wiktionary, neither should be regarded as perfect or as rubbish. Both will have some out of date entries or not cover all competing theories for some entries.

Answer (score 4):

English word "and" is cognate to another English word "end", both originating from PIE root ***a̯ent-*** meaning "end" (***a̯entom*** literally meant "end" in PIE). The meaning shifted to "in front of" as in ***a̯enti*** and later to "near", "next", "besides".

The meaning of "and" was conducted in PIE with a clitic ***-q̆e(t)*** which was attached to the last word, like Latin -que ("senatus populusque", which means "senate and the people"). This clitic comes from the same root as the PIE word ***q̆eta̯*** "pair" and has pre-PIE origin (cognates produced the numerals for "two" in Uralic languages).

There was no conjunction "and" in PIE, although, one could use the adverb ***e̯eti*** meaning "in addition", "also", "besides".

This word exactly evolved into Latin conjunction "et".

Comment: You say "The meaning of 'and' was conducted in PIE with a clitic -q̆e", but then you say "There was no conjunction 'and' in PIE". So do you mean that there was a word 'and', but no conjunction 'and'? Or, to put it another way - was  q̆e as frequently used in PIE as it is used in English?

Comment: @sashoalm it was a clitic, not conjunction.

Comment: Pokorny offers a different etymology for *and*:  Ein ganz verschiedenes Wort ist nhd. und, ahd. unti, anti, enti u. dgl., as. endi, ags. engl. and `und', anord. en(n) `und, aber', das mit ai. áthā̆ `darauf, dann, desgleichen', av. aϑā̆ `ebenso', osk. ant m. Akk. `usque ad', lit. iñt m. Akk. `nach' (aber s. oben), toch. В entwe`also' zu *en, n̥ `in' gehört.

Comment: @Bert Barrois in what sense this etymology is different?

Comment: Pokorny is saying that it does not come from ANT.  He does not really explain his reasoning.

Comment: Are your letters ‹e̯›, ‹a̯› equivalent to ‹h₁›, ‹h₂›?

Comment: Why do you say *h₂ent- meant "end"? Anatolian evidence seems to point to "front" or "fore".

Comment: Why has this answer been upvoted? There is definitely no consensus in the field that the Indo-European and Uralic languages are genetically related, nor any widespread belief in the field that the Uralic numeral ‘two’ derives from the same source as that Indo-European item whether through mutual inheritance or borrowing. This is a crank answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is "and" a recent word?: *No; it's been used for at least 2,000 years. The same word occurs in other Germanic languages such as German 'und'. It is a variant of teh word 'end' which has a good I-E history.*

If so, what word performed its function before that?: *Germanic also had an ending -ḫwe added to the second word in the 'and' construction that existed into written times in Gothic and was related to Latin '-que'.*

Did PIE have an unrelated word for "and", and if so, why did such a common word fall away from usage? *See the last answer; it fell out of use because when Germanic became a strongly first syllable stress language (sometime before or as it split into its descendants) final syllables became unstressed. You can see the problem if you consider it would have become Modern english '-gh'.*

Is "and" a cognate to Latin "et"? *No*